# How to implement macros in Flex/FlashDevelop/AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I am new to using the Flex Compiler with FD, although certainly not new to flash/as3 and FD. Currently, i have been compiling my applications with FD/CS3 and want to make the switch to the flex compiler. One of the main things i want to experiment with the flex compiler is using Macros in AS3. For instance, say i have some extremely expensive operation that i wish to carry out:

```
private function Main():void
{
extremelyExpensiveOperation(params);
}
```

but i want to avoid the cost of a function lookup. So instead of using a function lookup I do something like

```
private function Main():void
{
<macro expandExtremelyExpensiveOperationHere(params)/>
}
```

obviously the syntax doesn't have to look exactly like that, but the macro gets expanded before compilation thus avoiding function lookup. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use misch's [preprocessor](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1188) ... it supports macros as well ...

greetz

back2dos